# Octave (or MATLAB) / operator

Tags: vector, operators, octave, matrix-multiplication

I wonder what / operator does in Octave. (I am not sure whether it works the same way in MATLAB)

```
V = [1; 2; 3]
```

then

```
1 / V = [0.071429 0.142857 0.214286]
```

I know that ./ operator does element-wise division of vectors or matrices.
Then what does / operator do?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is described in the [documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.1/Arithmetic-Ops.html):

> `x / y`
>
> Right division. This is conceptually equivalent to the expression
>
> ```
> (inverse (y') * x')'
> ```
>
> but it is computed without forming the inverse of `y’`.
>
> If the system is not square, or if the coefficient matrix is singular, a minimum norm solution is computed.

MATLAB has exactly the same behavior, see its [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html).